# Why do I need to cast @types/parse5 types?

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with `parse5` in combination with `@types/parse5` _v5.0.2_using TypeScript.

The function signature of entry function `parse` is:

```
export function parse(html: string, options?: ParserOptions): Document;
```

However when I want to use `Document` I can not access the `childNodes` property. It turns out that `Document` is defined as such:

```
/**
 * Generic Document interface.
 * Cast to the actual AST interface (e.g. {@link parse5.DefaultTreeDocument}) to get access to the properties.
 */
export type Document = DefaultTreeDocument | object;
```

I am flummoxed! Why is it defined like this?

If I always need to cast, then what is the point? If I don't always need to cast, but under certain circumstances can expect the `Document` to *not* be a `DefaultTreeDocument` then what can I expect?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem like there is much point to Document being defined in such a way since you'll just be casting it to DefaultTreeDocument anyway, literally per their comment.